# Drag and drop not working with jqxtree

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, jqxtree

I use jqxTree to view my tree. I want to drag some element and drop on Droppable area.

```
$(".dragItem").draggable({
   revert: "true",
   revertDuration: 0,
   helper: 'clone',
   cancel : 'span',
   refreshPositions: true,
   containment: "parent"
 });

$(".dragItem").css({"position": ""});

$("#log").droppable({
    accept: ".dragItem",
    drop: function(event){
    alert("Dropped");
   }
});
```

Above Code is given in fiddle. 
Can anyone say why the drag and drop is not working
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/7TT7r/63/)

Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Comment: No it was not working in my project. When I drag  an element with the list expanded, it is not getting dropped into my canvas. As the list is very long and its height is extended more  than the canvas height, it is not dropping into it.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `dragEnd` handler to your tree config like below.
The `event` argument passed to this handler has plenty of info, I just used some for demo purpose. Check fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/1fzqtzsz/).

```
  $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
       height: '300px',
       ...
       dragEnd: function (event) {
          $('#log').append(event.label);
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that alert was mistyped, I've updated the code

```
 drop: function(event){
//alert();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1fzqtzsz/1/